# No overload for method ' ' takes 8/11 arguments

Tags: c#

I have these 2 code snippets in one dll file:

```
public void AddDocumentSet(
    string siteUrl,
    string libName,
    string docSetName,
    string mSISDN,
    string accountNumber,
    string hardCopyLocation,
    string verifiedBy,
    DateTime veriDate)
{
    // ...
} 

public void AddDocument(
    string siteUrl,
    string libName,
    string docListUrl,
    string docName,
    byte[] docStream,
    string mSISDN,
    string accountNumber,
    string hardCopyLocation,
    string documentName,
    string verifiedBy,
    DateTime veriDate)
{
    // ...
}
```

And I am calling them from another script C# script inside program.

```
r.AddDocumentSet(
    "http://--link--/",
    "Archive",
    "Earchive/Documents " + 
        Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value, 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\MSISDN").Value.ToString(), 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value.ToString(), 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Hard Copy Location").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verified by").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Date of Verifica00tion").Value.ToString()
);

// ...

r1.AddDocument(
    "http://--link--/",
    "Archive",
    "Earchive/Documents " +
        Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value+"/",
    "contract_" +
        Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value + "(" +
        Document.Field("Document Section 1\\MSISDN").Value + ").pdf",
    bytes,
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\MSISDN").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Hard Copy Location").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Document Name").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verified by").Value.ToString(),
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Date of Verifica00tion").Value.ToString()
);
```

And I get these errors:

> No overload for method 'AddDocumentSet' takes '8' arguments (line 6, pos 1)
>
> No overload for method 'AddDocument' takes '11' arguments (line 69, pos 1)

I am not a C# rockstar but I have tried everything. rebuilt dll, rewriten the snippets again, but nothing helped. I hope someone could show me the right code.

Comment: The problem is easy. You are passing more arguments to the method than you should.

Comment: You should really break you parameters down

Comment: can you show me right code please?

Comment: @plasmid Like Nahuel has already said.... the amount of parameters doesn't match.

Comment: @LPK I understood it, but how it should be ?

Comment: @plasmid Its your code? I don't know what you need there

Comment: this code is written by previous emplyee i have added these to code:

[- listItem["Verified by"] = (object) verifiedBy;
 listItem["Date of verification"] = (object) veriDate; -]

and 

[- file.ListItemAllFields["Verified by"] = (object) verifiedBy;
file.ListItemAllFields["Date of Verification"] = (object) veriDate; -]

and called them from the script, and these errors started

Comment: You're passing 6 and 9 arguments to that method, but the overloads you've shown here take 8 and 11 arguments respectively. You may want to format that second call so each argument occupies a single line, to make this sort of problem a little easier to spot. Also note that the last argument has to be a `DateTime`, not a `string`.

Comment: It's the universe telling you that your method is expecting too many parameters in the first place. Try redesigning it.  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics

Comment: @PieterWitvoet but why it worked till I did not add two arguments and called them. Because everything changed from initial call is, I have added 2 and called 2.

Comment: You're not going to get a correct answer until you post the actual code. But try @Pieter Witvoet suggestion - make the final argument in each a string.

Comment: @BeanFrog I Have added it

Comment: Have you tried converting Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Date of Verifica00tion").Value.ToString() to a date yet?

Comment: @plasmid: so it looks like you updated the methods but not the code that calls those methods. If you add a parameter to a method you must also update all code that calls that method to supply an extra argument.

Answer (score 1):

Its just basic compilation errors:

- Your functions expect DateTime as the final parameter, but you are passing a string instead.
- the number of parameters may be incorrect in the call to AddDocument().

Comment: "http://--link--/" [1],
    "Archive"[2],
    "Earchive/Documents " + 
        Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value [3], 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\MSISDN").Value.ToString()[4], 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Account").Value.ToString()[5], 
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Hard Copy Location").Value.ToString()[6],
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verified by").Value.ToString()[7],
    Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Date of Verifica00tion").Value.ToString()[8]

Comment: "http://--link--/"[1],
    "Archive"[2],
    "Earchive/Documents " +
        ...Field("..Section 1\\Account").Value+"/"[3],
    "contract_" +
        ....Field(".... 1\\Account").Value + "(" +
        Document.Field(".... 1\\MSISDN").Value + ").pdf"[4],
    bytes[5],
    ...Field("...1\\MSISDN")./.ToString()[6],
    ...Field("... 1\\Account")./.ToString()[7],
    ...Field("... 1\\Hard Copy Location")./.ToString()[8],
    ...Field("... 1\\Document Name")./.ToString()[9],
    ...Field("... 1\\Verified by")./.ToString()[10],
    ...Field("... 1\\Date of Verifica00tion")./.ToString()[11]

Comment: I had to delete some words so that I can put numbers. as you see there params have the same count. But what you mean by datetime, veriDate is already DateTime type. and the second script should just call it and convert this date into string.

Comment: If an expression ends with .ToString(), then its a string.